# PHP explode, problems with my own logic

Tags: php

I need the user to submit rules on where to explode a string.

Lets say we have a string:

```
$str = "Age: 20 Town: London Country: UK";
```

Lets say the user wants the "UK" part of the string, so he inputs

```
$input = "Country:";
```

In this case :

```
$output = end(explode($input, $str));

$output would contain: "UK"
```

How would I do this if he wanted "London" ?

```
$str = "Age: 20 Town: London Country: UK";

$part = end(explode('Town:', $str));

$parts = explode('Country: UK', $part);

$parts[0]; -> London
```

But what would be the best way of doing this based on user input parameters for explode, I basically want to give the option to cut something out of the string, which has to be based on rules that can be repeated for further strings that contain the same base substrings, such as Country, Age, etc..

**EDIT 1:**

I dont think i was clear enough, my bad.

Basically user input should target the sroundings of the value wanted:

$str = "Age: 20 Town: London Country: UK";
   $userinput = "Town: {some wildcard like #!#} Country:"

what function / combination of functions could i use to fish for the wildcard and return the substring in that location?

**EDIT 2:** I experimented and found a solution

Output wanted = Copenhagen

```
$string = "Age: 20 Town: Copenhagen Location: Denmark";

$input = "Town: #!# Location:";

$rules = explode('#!#', $input);

$part = explode($rules[0], $string);

$part = explode($rules[1], $part[1]);

echo $part[0]; ->Copenhagen
```

Comment: You are bound to run into problems here, what if a key or a value contains multiple words separated by spaces like `New York`? You will not be able to distinguish between keys and values.

Comment: Phew, was about to submit an answer but glad I didn't! I'll just watch and learn.

Comment: Sorry but the Edit is more confusing than the original post, can you reexplain the scenario in details?

Comment: Had to do correct some small mistakes, works now.

Comment: [Don't forget to **visit the stackoverflow TOUR** to guide you on how to best use this site.](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions to the rescue:

```
$field = 'Town';
$re = preg_quote($field, '/');
$matches = array();
preg_match("/$re: ([^ ]*)/", 'Age: 20 Town: London Country: UK', $matches);
echo $matches[1];   # London
```

Given two fields you can get whatever text lies between them like this:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match("/Age: (.*) Country:/", 'Age: 20 Town: London Country: UK', $matches);
echo $matches[1];   # 20 Town: London
```

Comment: How about "Town: Buenos Aires"?

Comment: The input format needs a proper specification. How about `Town: Buenos Aires Rate Of Birth: 42`?

Comment: The userinput is allowed to be the substrings surrounding the value wanted

Age: 20 Town: Buenos Aires Rate: Of Birth: 42

Userinput = "Town: Rate:" is there any way to get what is in between using regex ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$search = preg_quote($input, '#');
preg_match("#$search: ([^:]+) #", $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

This should even handle spaces in the input

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that your string over-uses spaces, which makes it difficult to parse values. If it is possible to delimit your values with characters *other* than spaces you will have an easier go of it.

eg:

```
$str = 'Age:20,Town:New York,Country:US';
$pairs = explode(',', $str);
$arr = array();
foreach($pairs as $pair) {
    $tmp = explode(':', $pair);
    $arr[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];
}
print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Age] => 20
    [Town] => New York
    [Country] => US
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$str = 'Age: 20 Town: London Country: UK';
$input = 'Town: #!# Country:';
$parts = explode(' ',$str);
$sides = explode(' #!# ',$input);
$left = $sides[0]; $right = $sides[1];
$length = count($parts);
$output = '';
for($i = 0 ; $i<$length ; $i++) {
    if($parts[$i] == $right) {
        for($j = $i+1 ; $j<$length ; $j++) {
            if($parts[$j]==$left) break;
            $output .= $parts[$j];
        }
    }
}

echo $output;
```

Tested, working.

Output:

```
UK
```